# How to submit $store from Alpine.js via Htmx

Tags: alpine.js, htmx

I have a table where each row has a checkbox. I am using Alpine.js $store to store the values that are checked in an array

I am using $store because I also have a select all and an infinite scroll on the page so when selecting all, not all the checkboxes are actually in the DOM.

I want to send the value of the $store in an htmx POST request.

I have an ideas of how to do it, but I'm wondering if there is a more semantic way.

Set a data-attr on the element to the value of the $store using x-bind and submit that using `hx-vals`. I have attempted this and it works, however it submits it as one string value comma separated (which is not a big deal to parse on the backend).

```html
<button hx-post='/example' x-bind:data-my-values="$store.values" hx-vals='{"myValues":event.target.dataset.myValues}'
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply let *htmx* access to the *AlpineJs store* via JS:

```HTML
<button hx-post='/example' hx-vals='js:{"myValues": {...Alpine.store("values")}}'>
```

in the example above I assumed that you have an array of values ​​that you want to send into the *myValues* variable, you will have to adapt the contents of *myValues* ​​to your needs

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize you could just do it like that. I had tried `$store.values` but that of course did not work. Much Appreciated!